How to access a picture pasted in the Excel cell and include it in a html string using VBA?
There is an Excel sheet with pictures pasted in cells (using paste picture in cell) in column 1. Column 2 is for images description. Example of images pasted in cells is here.
How to include an image from specific cell, e.g. ws.Cells(1,1), in an HTML string used for constructing email body?
In my script staring from If it does not work. I saw there are Shapes and Pictures, but they also didn't work.
Sub SendEmailAutomatically()
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object
Dim strBody As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

' Set a reference to the "Table1" sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

' Initialize the email body
strBody = "<p>Dear Team!<br>" & _
          "Find figures below:</p>"

For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
        strBody = strBody & _
                  "<br><p>Figure:" & i & ":</p><br>" & _
                  ws.Cells(i,1).Value & "<br>" & ws.Cells(i,2).Value & "<br>"
    End If
Next i

' Create Outlook application
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

' Set email properties
With OutlookMail
    .To = "email.address@company.name"
    .Subject = "Report " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YY")
    .HTMLBody = strBody ' Set the HTML-formatted content
    .Send
End With

' Clean up
Set OutlookMail = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub

